# Is it dangerous to have local variables refer to other local variables?

Tags: c++, reference, destructor

Take these two classes for instance:

```
struct Owned {
    Owned() : i() { }

    void print() { cout << ++i << endl; }

    int i;
};

struct Owner {
    Owner(Owned& o) : o(o) { }

    Owned& o;

    ~Owner() { o.print(); }
};
```

Is it dangerous to use them in this way?

```
int main() {
    Owned owned;
    Owner owner(owned);
}
```

It seems that, depending on the order in which they are destructed, that this could cause the destructor of `owner` to call a function on a destroyed `owned`. Is the order of destruction of local variables defined, and how can you make a situation where two instances refer to each other work?

Forgive me if this is common knowledge, I haven't read anything about it anywhere though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Local variables are destroyed in the opposite order of being created. In your case, you're fine, since `owner` will always be destroyed before `owned`.

`§6.6 [stmt.jump] p2`

> On exit from a scope (however accomplished), objects with automatic storage duration (3.7.3) that have been constructed in that scope are destroyed in the reverse order of their construction.

However, care has to be taken if you can reassign the owned member after construction.

> how can you make a situation where two instances refer to each other work?

Don't have them access each other in their destructor. Or make clear who exactly gets destroyed first, maybe with a callback or flag that gets passed. Example:

```
struct two;
struct one{
  two* other;

  one(two* o = nullptr) : other(o) {}
  ~one(){ if(other) other.other = nullptr; }
};

struct two{
  one* other;
  two(one* o = nullptr) : other(o) {}
  ~one(){ if(other) other.other = nullptr; } 
};
```

This will ensure that both objects never reference a non-existent one.

Mutually referencing objects are very rare anyways.

Comment: Ok, this is basically what I was thinking. Thanks.

Comment: By "make two instances refer to each other" I presume you mean having 'owned' and 'owner' both contain a member reference of the opposing type.  Doing it THAT way, you can't really. But that's because references can't be reassigned to new referents after creation.  If you just a) switched to pointers and b) performed the assignment outside of the constructors (detaching you from that particular timing issue) then you've got full reign on what can get to what.   But with great power.... :p

Comment: @Michael: Just assign to the `other` member after construction. I already have pointers there. `one o; two t(&o); o.other = &t;`

Comment: @Xeo *sigh* Yes. Yes you're absolutely right.  I'm fritzing out. I was looking at the OP's code when I wrote that. (Plus I could've sworn there was a follow-up question in a comment asking about mutual references.  Damn. these edits happen too fast.)

Answer (score 1):

`Owner` doesn't actually own `owned` it just has a reference to it, so when it is destroyed owned destructor won't be called.

Comment: The worry is that `owned` will be destroyed before `owner` and as such the destructor of the latter will access a dangling reference.

Answer (score 1):

What you've written isn't dangerous in anyway, variables in the same scope in C++ are destructed in a defined (reverse-ordered manner).  Something like this, however, is dangerous,

```
int main() {
    Owner owner();
    {
        Owned owned;
        owner.setOwned(owned);
    }

    owner.doSomethingWithOwned();
}
```

Because owned no longer exists, it was forced out of scope.  This also applies to setting local variables to be references in objects on the heap.

Comment: Functions don't have methods named `setOwned` :)

Comment: You're correct.  But, if you image setOwned copied the reference in a similar manor to the constructor, you can see how an out-of-scope object shouldn't be referred to (since it doesn't exist).

Comment: Yes, the answer is correct (AFAIK) apart from the function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

This is safe, local objects are destroyed in the reverse order in which they are created.

Comment: So then if I declare them another way, the behaviour is undefined? Also what about the second question?

Comment: @SethCarnegie: How do you declare them in another way?